# Why is my python code not opening a Tkinter window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, tkinter, stock

I want to make a stock app, but when I run the code, no Tkinter window shows up, for some reason. Please help me, and I have hid my (changed) api key for security reasons, as pointed out in my last question. The console returns no error, but doesn't open the window.

```
import http.client as client
from tkinter import *
import json

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

conn = client.HTTPSConnection("realstonks.p.rapidapi.com")

headers = {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': "[CLASSIFIED]",
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': "realstonks.p.rapidapi.com"
}

inputbox = Text(root, padx = 40, pady = 30).pack()
name = ""

def layout(data_obj):
  vol = data_obj['total_vol']
  price = data_obj['price']
  percent = data_obj['change_percentage']
  if percent < 0:
      fg = 'red'
  elif percent > 0:
      fg = 'green'
  elif percent == 0:
      fg = 'gray'
  title_widget = Label(root, text = name, font = ("arial bold", 50), underline = True).pack()
  vol_widget = Label(root, text = vol + " in total.", font = ("arial bold", 40)).pack()
  price_widget = Label(root, text = str(price) + " dollars per share.", font = ("arial bold", 30)).pack()
  percent_widget = Label(root, text = str(percent) + "%", font = ("arial bold", 20), fg = fg).pack()

def search_function():
  name = inputbox.get("1.0","end-1c")
  conn.request("GET", "/" + name.upper(), headers=headers)
  res = conn.getresponse()
  data = res.read()
  # print(data)
  data_obj = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
  layout(data_obj)

search = Button(root, text = "Search Info", background = "gray", command = search_function).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: FWIW, I get a window when I run your code. I don't see anything in your code that might prevent that.

Comment: `conn = client.HTTPSConnection("realstonks.p.rapidapi.com")` is maybe blocking the rest of your code. Add a timeout to it, like `client.HTTPSConnection("realstonks.p.rapidapi.com", timeout=10)` [see the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html)

Comment: The text box is a little big so that the button is pushed out of the viewable area of the window.  Try removing `root.geometry("500x500")` and you will see the button.